# Does passportjs LocalStrategy allow more parameters than the default username and password?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm new to javascript, node,and passportjs. Sorry if this is incorrect. I'd like to use 3 parameters in my passport local strategy: ***username, email, password***. Is it possible? If so how?

According to passportjs: "By default, LocalStrategy expects to find credentials in parameters named username and password. If your site prefers to name these fields differently, options are available to change the defaults." But can i add more paramaters?

I tried this:

```
 passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'username',
        emailField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, username, email, password, done) {
        console.log("username:"+username + "email:"+email + "pwd:"+password);
    }));
```

but it logs email as password and password as some function

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is there is the passReqToCallback argument.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
 {
   usernameField: 'username',
   passwordField: 'password',
   passReqToCallback: true

 },
function (req, username, password, done) {
  {
    fieldName: req.body.fieldName,
    password: password,
    username: username
  }
}));
```

Comment: This answer also works fine when I use it on NestJs

Answer (score 7):

I suspect what you are trying to do is save additional information on your user when he signs up.

All your information is store in `req.body` so you just need to save it in your callback:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'your_form_username_or_email_fieldname',
    passwordField: 'your_form_password_fieldname'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    // ...

    // set the user's credentials
    newUser.username = req.body.username;
    newUser.email = req.body.email;
    newUser.password = newUser.generateHash(password);

    // ....

  }
));
```

There is no need to change the local strategy as it only needs 2 arguements (the email/username + the password)

Answer (score 1):

The req.body carries the form's data (fields with names),
and this is pasted into passport Local-login.

My Login Form has three field
companyId, email and password.

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
},
function(req, email, password, done) {
    if (email){
        email = email.toLowerCase();
        var id = db.generateHash(email,'sha256',10);

        // here i get to companyId for the body to look at the Company's users Table
        var table = "Users-" + req.body.companyId; 

        db.getOneScan(table, "id", id, null, function(err,user){.....}
           // if user exist in data base check password is Valid and return user
        }
```

I know this is a little late but I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

LocalStrategy only expects two parameters named username and password. But you can name them differently setting the defaults as following:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'your_form_username_or_email_fieldname',
    passwordField: 'your_form_password_fieldname'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    // ...
  }
));
```

The doc is here: http://passportjs.org/guide/username-password/

ps. The "some function" you are talking about must be the callback function done ;)

Answer (score -1):

Just a note in case anyone else finds this while Googling: if req.body doesn't work for you, use req.query instead.

Comment: req.query is for query string or GET request while the question is about post request