# NestJS passport validate with more options other than user and password

Tags: node.js, authentication, nestjs, nestjs-passport

I'm trying to prevent users of type "member" from accessing a dashboard. This dashboard shares the same authentication endpoint as the main site. In the POST request to the `/login` endpoint I'm trying to pass another paramater `env="dashboard` so that I can tell then return a 400 if the user is a "member" instead of an "admin".

The problem is that this parameter gets stripped out when it reaches the `validate()` callback in the local strategy. So as far as I can tell it looks like it only expects a username and password. Is there a way to achieve this whilst still keeping the `LocalStrategy` with the `validate`?

**local.strategy.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'local') {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      usernameField: 'email',
      environment: 'environment',
    });
  }
  async validate(
    email: string,
    password: string,
    environment: string 
//this environment doesn't make it to the getAuthenticatedUser method despite being on
// the request object 
  ): Promise<User> {
    return this.authService.getAuthenticatedUser(email, password, environment);
  }
}
```

I have tried doing like suggested in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68171886/nestjs-passport-local-strategy-validate-method-never-called)
and add it to the `super()` but still get the same result and when I log the value of environment I get: `[Function: verified]`

The providers in the **auth.module.ts** look like this:

```
providers: [
    AuthService,
    LocalStrategy,
    JwtStrategy,
    ApiKeyStrategy,
    AdminApiKeyStrategy,
  ],
```

Is there anything I'm missing or is it possible at all to achieve what I'm trying?

Comment: Actually found an answer to this on another question that I hadn't found before. Have flagged it as duplicate.

Comment: I thought the other post's link was visible to everybody at the top of this post but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726921/does-passportjs-localstrategy-allow-more-parameters-than-the-default-username-an) it is if that's not the case.